# Htaccess: remove query from urls and redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a Forum on my site and need to redirect weirdly generated urls.

Every url contains `?id=`, eg:

https://www.example.com/forum/topic/casualthread/page/25?id=casualthread

and I need to **remove the `?id=` and everything that follows** in order to have:

https://www.example.com/forum/topic/casualthread/page/25

I am trying to modify this code I found here on Stackoverflow with very scarce results:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Make sure there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*  /?id= [R=301,L]
```

The htaccess file i am editing is in the forum directory:
https://www.example.com/forum/

and it redirects everything to the homepage https://www.example.com: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, google only found those I mentioned. Starkeen answer did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since not just `id`, but also some other parameter(s) may be present in the query string, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(^id=[^&]*&?|&id=[^&]*)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+) /$1?%1%3 [R=301,L]
```